# Simple Sum and Subtract Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

**Table1:**
    id | car1 | car2 | car3 | car4

```
**Table2:**
id | windows | doors | engines
```

I have this sql code:

```
sum(car1) + sum(car2) + sum(car3) + sum(car4) as 'tot_cars',
sum('doors') as 'tot_doors'
'tot_doors' - 'tot_cars' as 'door_rest'
```

I've tried this also and not working:

```
sum(car1) + sum(car2) + sum(car3) + sum(car4) as 'tot_cars',
sum('doors') as 'tot_doors'
('tot_doors' - 'tot_cars' as 'door_rest')
```

This:

```
sum(car1) + sum(car2) + sum(car3) + sum(car4) as 'tot_cars',
sum('doors') as 'tot_doors'
('tot_doors - tot_cars as door_rest')
```

And this:

```
sum(car1) + sum(car2) + sum(car3) + sum(car4) as 'tot_cars',
sum('doors') as 'tot_doors'
('tot_doors - tot_cars') as 'door_rest'
```

All not working.

Still I'm having errors in SQLSyntax, it said cannot find '***door_rest***' field in the database.

There are no problem with joining the two tables, because when I was querying the '***tot_cars***' it showed the data on my page. But I'm having trouble with the '***door_rest***' field.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use single quotes for column aliases.  The value of:

```
sum('doors')
```

is 0, because it is summing the string `'doors'`.  And, MySQL converts strings to integers based on leading digits -- which results in 0 in this case.  Only escape names that need to be escaped, to avoid extra typing and make your queries more clear.  Use the proper escape character (a backtick).  And then choose names that don't need to be escaped.

Your problem is that you cannot use an alias in the same select, so:

```
sum(car1) + sum(car2) + sum(car3) + sum(car4) as tot_cars,
sum(doors) as tot_doors,
(sum(car1) + sum(car2) + sum(car3) + sum(car4) - sum(doors)) as door_rest
```

Answer (score 2):

Aliases are not available on the SELECT clause, so you have to repeat the sum:

```
select
  sum(car1) + sum(car2) + sum(car3) + sum(car4) as tot_cars,
  sum(doors) as tot_doors,
  sum(doors) - sum(car1) - sum(car2) - sum(car3) - sum(car4) as door_rest
```

also you can just use one sum function for each calculated field (unless you have null values, but you have to fix your original query anyway if there are some null values):

```
select
  sum(car1 + car2 + car3 + car4) as tot_cars,
  sum(doors) as tot_doors,
  sum(doors - car1 - car2 - car3 - car4) as door_rest
```

Comment: Tried that and got new error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near sum(doors - car1 - car2 - car3 - car4) as 'door_rest'

Comment: @kris sorry I didn't  see that you were using `'`, please use backticks ` or just no qualifier, like in my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `alias` name in same `select` query. Use the calculated field in outer query and make the original query as `sub-select`

```
select (tot_doors - tot_cars) as 'door_rest'
(
sum(car1) + sum(car2) + sum(car3) + sum(car4) as 'tot_cars',
sum(doors) as 'tot_doors'
from yourtable
) A
```

This is how query is logically proccessed

```
FROM clause
WHERE clause
SELECT clause
GROUP BY clause
HAVING clause
ORDER BY clause
```